# Issue with optional binding using lazy var

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, lazy-initialization, optional-binding

I am working with a UIPageViewController and I have an array of viewcontrollers

```
lazy var subviewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return[
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1") as! ViewController1,
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2,
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController3") as! ViewController3
    ]
}()

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if let subview3 = subviewControllers[2] as? ViewController3 {
        subview3.customBar.alpha = 0.8 // <- error on this line
    }
}
```

But sometimes I have this error when I make a scroll:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Which line exactly is causing your error?

Comment: subview3.customBar.alpha = 0.8

Comment: You are accessing the view controller's outlets too soon. You should never directly access a view controller's outlets. Set a property and let the view controller update it's own outlets at the proper time.

Comment: Can you provide me an example please?  This is my code @IBOutlet  weak var customBar: customView!

Comment: When reviewing the duplicate, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49818897/1226963) since it closest addresses your issue and solution.

Comment: This example is just I needed, thanks